# Flutter windows-desktop: Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly

Tags: windows, flutter, cmake

I have a Problem with launching my Flutter App in Windows. If I create and run the windows app with `flutter build windows` it works and I can start the app. But if I want to start it with `flutter run` there is an error. I assume it has something to do with the dubugger.

```
Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.282]
Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 95.0.4638.69
Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 95.0.1020.44
[1]: Windows (windows)
[2]: Chrome (chrome)
[3]: Edge (edge)
Please choose one (To quit, press "q/Q"): 1
Running "flutter pub get" in school...                             541ms
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
Building Windows application...
Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly.
Error launching application on Windows.
```

Here is my Flutter Docotr Output:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.282], locale de-DE)
    • Flutter version 2.5.3 at D:\Progamming\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 18116933e7 (4 weeks ago), 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
    • Engine revision d3ea636dc5
    • Dart version 2.14.4

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at D:\Progamming\Android\SDK
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Users\fito0\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\AndroidStudio\ch-0\203.7784292\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.5)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.11.31729.503
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Users\fito0\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\AndroidStudio\ch-0\203.7784292
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.2)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Users\fito0\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\212.5457.46
    • Flutter plugin version 62.0.3
    • Dart plugin version 212.5632

[√] VS Code (version 1.62.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\fito0\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.28.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.282]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 95.0.4638.69
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 95.0.1020.44

• No issues found!
```

Here is the verbose log of the crash from `flutter run`

```
[...]
[  +24 ms]   -- Install configuration: "Debug"
[ +455 ms]   -- Up-to-date: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/icudtl.dat
[        ]   -- Up-to-date: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/flutter_windows.dll
[        ]   -- Up-to-date: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/connectivity_plus_windows_plugin.dll
[   +7 ms]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets
[        ]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/AssetManifest.json
[        ]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/FontManifest.json
[        ]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/fonts
[        ]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/fonts/Cabin
[        ]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/fonts/Cabin/Cabin-Italic-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf
[   +1 ms]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/fonts/Cabin/Cabin-VariableFont_wdth,wght.ttf
[   +1 ms]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/fonts/Exo_2
[        ]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/fonts/Exo_2/Exo2-Italic-VariableFont_wght.ttf
[   +1 ms]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/fonts/Exo_2/Exo2-VariableFont_wght.ttf
[   +1 ms]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/fonts/Gluten
[        ]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/fonts/Gluten/Gluten-VariableFont_wght.ttf
[   +1 ms]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.otf
[   +3 ms]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/fonts/Schoolvito(1).png
[   +1 ms]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/fonts/Schoolvito.png
[        ]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/fonts/Teko
[        ]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/fonts/Teko/Teko-Bold.ttf
[   +3 ms]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/fonts/Teko/Teko-Light.ttf
[   +1 ms]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/fonts/Teko/Teko-Medium.ttf
[   +1 ms]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/fonts/Teko/Teko-Regular.ttf
[   +2 ms]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/fonts/Teko/Teko-SemiBold.ttf
[   +2 ms]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/kernel_blob.bin
[ +115 ms]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/NOTICES
[   +2 ms]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/NOTICES.Z
[   +1 ms]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/packages
[        ]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/packages/cupertino_icons
[        ]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/packages/cupertino_icons/assets
[        ]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/packages/cupertino_icons/assets/CupertinoIcons.ttf
[   +1 ms]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/pictures
[        ]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/pictures/Book-Placeholder.jpg
[   +1 ms]   -- Installing: C:/Users/fito0/IdeaProject/school/build/windows/runner/Debug/data/flutter_assets/pictures/Profile-Placeholder.png
[   +8 ms] FinalizeBuildStatus:
[   +1 ms]   Die Datei "x64\Debug\INSTALL\INSTALL.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" wird gelöscht.
[        ]   Aktualisieren des Timestamps von "x64\Debug\INSTALL\INSTALL.tlog\INSTALL.lastbuildstate".
[        ] Die Erstellung von Projekt "C:\Users\fito0\IdeaProject\school\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj" ist abgeschlossen (Standardziele).
[        ] Der Buildvorgang wurde erfolgreich ausgeführt.
[        ]     0 Warnung(en)
[        ]     0 Fehler
[   +1 ms] Verstrichene Zeit 00:00:07.10
[  +17 ms] Building Windows application... (completed in 7,5s)
[  +22 ms] Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly.
[   +1 ms] Error launching application on Windows.
[  +47 ms] "flutter run" took 9.951ms.
[   +3 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:669:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1125:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:288:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:236:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:92:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           
           
[  +14 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 13ms
[        ] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

My installed `dependencies`:

```
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.8
  provider: ^6.0.1
  intl: ^0.17.0
  http: ^0.13.4
  path_provider: ^2.0.4
  connectivity_plus: ^2.0.1
```

Unfortunately, I do not know how to solve the problem.... I'm looking for quite a while, without result. Does anyone know how I can solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

First of all Open Your Your_project\build\windows folder.
You can see there is file named app.so.
Just Copy app.so and Paste this file on Your_project\build\windows\runner\Debug\data.
Now, Your problem is solved.

https://exerror.com/error-waiting-for-a-debug-connection-the-log-reader-stopped-unexpectedly-or-never-started-error-launching-application-on-windows/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).